# App crashes only on Android 5.0 with a VerifyError

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

My app runs fine on every version except on 5.0.
On that version every activity which has a bundle passing it some data crashes..

Here is the logcat:

```
05-09 01:37:43.733 6371-6371/com.pttest.com.pockettankstips E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pttest.com.pockettankstips, PID: 6371
java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.pttest.com.pockettankstips.compare because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'com.pttest.com.pockettankstips.compare' appears in /data/data/com.pttest.com.pockettankstips/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Here is my code to open the Activity:

```
Intent co = new Intent("com.pttest.com.pockettankstips.compare");
Bundle compare = new Bundle();
compare.putString("index", "3 Shot");
co.putExtras(compare);
startActivity(co);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Select Second Weapon to Compare!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
break;
```

And how I receive the Bundle in the Activity I am about to open..

```
c1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cspin1);
c2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cspin2);
c1.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.spinada, weapon));
c2.setAdapter(new MyAdapter1(this, R.layout.spinada, weapon1));
c1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
c2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
Bundle compare = getIntent().getExtras();
String compone = compare.getString("index", "3 Shot");
String[] weaponone = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weapalpha);
x = Arrays.asList(weaponone).indexOf(compone);
c1.setSelection(x);
```

In the Activities where I try to send an `int` in the Bundle it works fine, but when I try to send a `String` it crashes..

Comment: post java code here. so we give better solution.

Comment: are you using emulator?

Comment: yes.. and in developer console it shows me that my app crashed on all of the devices with 5.0..

Comment: @VaibhaVDeshmukh in line `1572` which code is there ?

Comment: in original post i posted how i am using bundles... it works fine when i pass int value through bundle...

Answer (score 2):

I have an error to my previous project like below and I Solve see the answer.

> java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class
>        com.harshad.syncV4.android.module.ModuleTest because it failed
>        compile-time verification (declaration of
>        'com.harshad.syncV4.android.module.ModuleTest' appears in
>        /data/app/com.harshad.syncV4.android-1/base.apk)

#### Note :

this error occur in Android OS version 5.0.1.

#### My Code :

I am doing this in my code.

```
try {
   synchronized (this) {
      this.wait(100);
   }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   /* Exception message can be captured here */
}
```

**Synchronized block inside try / catch block**

When I set try / catch inside synchronized block - application start working as usual. By the way, prior to Android OS 5.0.1 there were no problem with such approach. I assume that this is because of the new ART compiler.

#### Correct way :

```
synchronized (this) {
   try {
      this.wait(testActionItem.getDelay());
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      /* Exception message can be captured here */
   }
}
```

Comment: where should i apply try catch? while launching the activity?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12286522)

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe  I have this error occure previous so  I Just describe it with Solution.

Comment: Although you may have the same error it still doesn't answer the question. Read the question carefully. There are many reasons for Rejecting class yours and the questions is different

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
String compone = compare.getString("index");
```

instead

```
String compone = compare.getString("index", "3 Shot");
```

in your second Activity which you want to open.

Hope this will help you.